# Sandwich and Drink Combination

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Working on some discrete homework: A customer at a fast food restaurant can order a burger with or without mustard, ketchup, pickle, or onion; a fish sandwich without lettuce, tomato, or tartar sauce; and a choice of 3 kinds of soft drinks or 2 kinds of milk shakes. How many different orders are possible if a customer can order at most 1 hamburger, 1 fish sandwich, and 1 beverage but can order less?

I figure there are 16 Burger combos, 9 fish sandwich combos, 3 soft drinks and 2 shakes. When I multiply all of those together, I am getting 864. The book, however, says that the answer should be 917. Could someone explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are only $8$ possible fish sandwiches, not $9$. Then, as the customer can only order one beverage, you should not multiply soft drinks and milkshakes - that would make "ordering soft drink $x$ and milkshake $y$" a valid order. Instead, you should consider that there are only $5$ beverages.

So you multiply $16 \cdot 8 \cdot 5$ - and you'll still get an answer different from the textbook. That's because they're considering the possibility of not ordering one specific item. So to each one of the possible hamburger, fish sandwich and beverage orders we add one more option: "no hamburger", "no fish sandwich", "no beverage".

This gives us $17 \cdot 9 \cdot 6 = 918$, one more than the answer in the textbook. Why? Because we can disregard the configuration "no hamburger, no fish sandwich, no beverage" as that doesn't count as an order. So we subtract $1$ and obtain the desired result.